# outlook 2013 how do you customise the buttons above the email in the preview pane

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I would like to remove the Reply All button from the links above the email in the preview pane. Note, this is *not* the buttons in the ribbon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not customize the Reply, Reply All, and Forward buttons at the top of Preview Pane.

[image]